# Match all places (coordinates lat,lng) within a certain XY radius

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

I have a database of places with their latitude and longitude. Is there any library or an API that lets you match all places that surround a specific point?

For instance, let's say I'd like to find all results in the database that have coordinates within the 15,000m radius of the origin coordinates 52.5200° N, 13.4050° E.

Is there any ready solution for it?

Thanks!

Comment: POSTGIS is specially made for this. If your app is going to make heavy use of spatial functions/utilities, you should consider switching to it.

If not you can take a look at `shapely`, Links:

https://automating-gis-processes.github.io/CSC18/lessons/L4/point-in-polygon.html
https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/46709/checking-if-a-point-is-in-a-circle

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you intend to search your database, the answers may differ. If you intend to use SQL, you could do as described [here](https://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong-db.html):

```
Select Id, Postcode, Lat, Lon,
       acos(sin(:lat)*sin(radians(Lat)) + cos(:lat)*cos(radians(Lat))*cos(radians(Lon)-:lon)) * :R As D
From MyTable
Where acos(sin(:lat)*sin(radians(Lat)) + cos(:lat)*cos(radians(Lat))*cos(radians(Lon)-:lon)) * :R < :rad
```

To select points from a database within a certain distance from a given latitude/longitude point, within a selection circle, you could use that query, where `rad` is your radius, 15000m in your example.